# Load iPhone photos to a Joomla website

Tags: iphone, joomla

I need following functionality

1. User logged in on a Joomla based website.
2. Program determines whether user logged in or not.
3. If user logged in, then the program fetch pictures from iPhone (photos
   folder) and upload them on the website.

The point which I cannot understand is that how to detect that user logged in or not. Is there any Joomla framework which allows me to do this?

And can I use Joomla API with Objective C?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla handles login so basically you need to have a joomla website with a template that fits into iphones & smartphones, you can try this for example mobilejoomla dot com but there's a lot of templatez that you can use (focus on "responsive templates" if you want one template for any screens)
To upload users pictures or files :
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management

If you are good at programming then you can you can hacks some free extensions to reduce the numbers of taps on the screen and display those pics with some more extensions:

There's a guy who build a bridge between cocoa and php check this out : 
http://www.slideshare.net/wezfurlong/hot-chocolate-you-got-cocoa-in-my-php

Answer (score 0):

To detect if a user is logged in, use this code in your script :

```
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    if ($user->guest==1) {
        //user not logged in
    } else {
        //user logged in, do some stuff
    }
```

More info available here : http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object